# Removing Time Portion from DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I remove the Time portion from DateTime before passing it to a GridView. I'm using VS2008 else I would be using Date :(

```
  DataTable datatablePlanning = new DataTable("Planning");

  DateTime begindate = DatePicker1.SelectedDate;

  DataRow detailregel = datatablePlanning.NewRow();
  detailregel["Date"] = begindate;
  datatablePlanning.Rows.Add(detailregel);

  GridView2.DataSource = datatablePlanning;
  GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: You can't remove it. You can set it to zeroes. What you probably want to do is set the _format_ of the `DateTime` for that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format your date.

```
detailregel["Date"] = begindate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or you can try

```
detailregel["Date"] = begindate.ToShortDateString();
```

For Different Format you can look at

> [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: `mm` => `MM`, `ToShort` => `ToShortDateString`?

Comment: yeah already changed the mm to MM, thanks for the heads up though:)

Answer (score 2):

You can format Date as follow...

```
detailregel["Date"] = begindate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

You can find fore info [DateTime Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

you can give the text property of binding text box like this Text='<%# Bind("Date","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'

Answer (score 1):

You can also format in design mode using EVAL in grid view item template:

```
   <%# Convert.ToDate(Eval("Your_Date")).ToShortDateString()%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bothered about the time part of the date in the gridview, just format it to show the date part

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date", "{0:MM/d/yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
```