# Error: Date Type Conversion from String in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

For the following code, I am receiving this error: "Conversion from String "10/22.2014 12:00:00 A10" to type 'Date' is not valid." Note - in comparison to the code, below - the error message's conversion of AM to A10.

### What I Am Trying To Do

I am trying to give a user the ability to query a database for transactions that occurred, today. In order to do this, I need to specify the timestamp for the transaction, i.e. `MM/dd/yyyy timestamp`. I have consulted the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx); however, am unable to get my code to function, properly.

By default, `Date` objects appear to drop their timestamp (this may be a result of the code I am working with, e.g. the casting); therefore, when specifying a date range of "today" (`Today's Data - Today's Date`), I am left with the default behaviour of the object: `Today's Date 12:00:00 AM - Today's Date 12:00:00 AM`. Regardless as to *why this is happening*, this is the problem with which I am left.

**The objective**: `MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM` - `MM/dd/yy 11:59:59 PM` (the day being the same).

My goal is to force a particular timestamp for a `Date` object (note this is not a `DateTime` object). By specifyiong the time range, I am able to grab all data from a database for today.

### What I've Got

Below, is the code and, below that, the description (I've tried to condense the code as much as possible). You'll also note that this is only half of the code, i.e. the `FromDate` portion (presumably the format can be replicated for the `ToDate`:

```
Public Shared Function ToFromDate(ByVal aValue As Object) As Date
    Dim Result As Date

    Try
        Result = CDate(aValue)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Result = Now
    End Try

    Result = CDate(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM}", Result))

    Return Result
End Function
```

The above code takes as an argument a `DateTime`, e.g. 10\10\2010 12:15:63 PM (and, for the purposes of my problem, the timestamp is included). Again, I am trying to take that `Date` with timestamp and change the time. `Result` receives `aValue`, casting the object as `Date` to "ensure" it is a date.

After `Result` receives a value (as when declaring a `Date` it is initialized to #12:00:00 AM#, interestingly enough), I attempt to `CDate()` a formatted `String` object. I have also attempted to remove the second cast, yet still receive the same error (the `Result = CDate(String...)` line throwing the error).

### Question(s)

The main question: how do I appropriately cast a date to include a specified time?
The second, trivial question: what's with the `#` surrounding the `Date`? Is this a SQL 'thing'?

Here's my work around for the above not working, so far:

```
    Dim Result As Date

    Dim DateString As String = CStr(aValue)
    Dim TestDateString As String = DateString.Substring(0, DateString.IndexOf("/"))
    Dim NewDateString As String = ""

    If TestDateString.Length = 2 Then
        NewDateString = DateString.Substring(0, 10)
    Else
        NewDateString = DateString.Substring(0, 8)
    End If


    NewDateString = NewDateString + " 12:00:00 AM"
    NewDateString = CObj("#" + NewDateString + "#")

    Result = CDate(NewDateString)

    Return Result
```

Comment: # signs surrounding a date is more of a MSAccess (sometimes VB) thing.

Comment: This SO post has a good example of what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971927/removing-time-portion-from-datetime

Comment: @tgolisch that's a different question, altogether.

Comment: Could you please clarify: why is it so different from this question?  The topic seems very similar to me (and maybe others on SO), otherwise I would not have suggested it.

Comment: @tgolisch I'll clarify, soon (gotta get home from work, first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a date is the number of ticks since a point in time. Formatting it to a string and then converting to a date does nothing but spin the wheels of your CPU.

Because of culture issues, you should always create dates using `NEW DATE(?,?,?,etc)`

Second, the `#` is a vb6 way of creating dates (and MS Access) that is there for backwards compatibility.

Third, If you have a date (no time or as of midnight), and you want it to be as of say 6AM, you simply add the time you want. IE:

```
Dim d As Date = New Date(2014,1,1)
d = d.AddHours(6)
'Result: d = 1/1/2014 6:00:00 AM
```

Lastly, if you have a date and time and you want to remove the time, there are many ways but this is the one I like:

```
Dim d As Date = Now
d = New Date(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day)
```

Comment: I appreciate the importance of cultural representations of time and the attempt to capture that with code; unfortunately, the powers at be do not (even though this is an international product). Didn't know about the "NEW DATE" bit.

Comment: The last portion answered the question, yes.